# Different ways of selecting $9$ cubes of various colors

Tags: combinatorics

> How many different ways can I select $9$ cubes, with at least $3$ blue cubes? There are $10$ white cubes, $17$ blue cubes, $11$ black cubes and $14$ red cubes?

My answer:
$$\binom{12}9 = \frac{12!}{9!(12-9)!} = 220$$

Is correct?

Comment: How many cubes do you have in total?

Comment: 52. There are 10 white cubes, 17 blue cubes, 11 black cubes and 14 red cubes.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please use [MathJax](https://www.onemathematicalcat.org/MathJaxDocumentation/TeXSyntax.htm) to format your posts.  To begin with, surround math expressions (including numbers) with `$` signs and use `_` for subscripts.  `$x_1$` comes out as $x_1$.

Comment: Then why are you choosing from $12$ besides other mistakes that you have?

Comment: Please explain your reasoning as well as giving an answer.  Your answer seems to have nothing to do with the problem.  I see that $12-9=3$, but I have no idea where $12$ comes from.  Also, how does relate to the requirement of *at least* $3$ blue cubes?

Comment: This has nothing to do with probability.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is wrong. The reason is the following: your solution basically answers the question without taking into account color and the total number of cubes, so it answers "In how many ways can we select $9$ cubes from $12$ cubes? While these cubes can be any color.

Solution:

First, you have $52$ cubes in total, this includes $17$ blue cubes $35$ non-blue cubes, to get the total number of ways you can get AT LEAST $3$ blue cubes out of $9$ you need to find the total number of ways you can get EXACTLY $3$ cubes, the total number of ways you can get EXACTLY $4$ cubes, etc... till the total numbers of ways you can get all $9$ cubes to be blue and add them together.

To get the total number of ways of getting $x$ blue cubes out of $9$ drawn you apply the following general formula:

$\binom{17}{x}*\binom{35}{9-x}$

Since you are choosing $x$ blue cubes out of $17$ and when you choose $x$ cubes you will have $9-x$ non-blue-cubes remaining as you need $9$ cubes in total, you multiply both combinations as for every way to choose $x$ blue cubes you have $\binom{35}{9-x}$ of choosing the rest.

So numbers of ways of choosing EXACTLY $3$ cubes you get:

$\binom{17}{3}*\binom{35}{6}$

You do this for $x=3,4,5,6,7,8,9$ and add them all up to get your final answer.